# Django Q filter not working as expected

Tags: python, django, django-q

I created a library style search form (where you can add new lines to further your search, with linking words like AND, OR, AND NOT, OR NOT) to allow them to build search statements in the form, which I then tried to turn into a Q Filter. For some reason, the filter I generate seems to return everything if there is an OR in it. (By 'or in it' I mean that the the user selected or as their statement).

Example: I wanted to create a Q Filter so that I would get objects with NAME for its datafield and Test as its value OR with Material as its datafield and Steel as its value.

When I print out the Q created, this is what I get:

```
(AND: (OR: (AND: ), (AND: ('value__icontains', 'Test'), ('represents__exact', <DataField: 3-Name>)), (NOT (AND: ('value__iexact', 'Steel'), ('represents__exact', <DataField: 6-Materials>)))))
```

Reading that statement, it seems like it should work, but it doesn't and seems to just return everything.

This isn't exactly what I have, but it is an example of what the form looks like:
[image]

UPDATE:
I changed my code so that the resulting Q statement is this instead:

```
(OR: (AND: ('value__icontains', 'er'), ('represents__exact', <DataField: 3-Name>)), (NOT (AND: ('value__iexact', 'er'), ('represents__exact', <DataField: 5-Keywords>))))
```

Or, in expanded form:

```
(OR:
    (AND:
        ('value__icontains', 'er'), ('represents__exact', <DataField: 3-Name>)
    ),
    (NOT
        (AND:
            ('value__iexact', 'er'), ('represents__exact', <DataField: 5-Keywords>)
        )
    )
)
```

Still, the following code prints out everything in the database:

```
    filtered = objects.filter(q)
    print("Filtered: ", filtered)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in the way you are generating the queryset.

Reorganizing the generated `Q` statement, it looks like the outermost `AND` does not have a second expression.

```
(AND: 
    (OR: 
        (AND: ), 
        (AND: 
           ('value__icontains', 'Test'), 
           ('represents__exact', <DataField: 3-Name>)
        ), 
        (NOT 
           (AND: 
               ('value__iexact', 'Steel'), 
               ('represents__exact', <DataField: 6-Materials>)
           )
         )
     )
)
```

Also the empty `(AND: ),` would pose problems too, so would have to figure out a way to remove the empty `Q` object

P.S:This is not a complete answer, but a direction, because without looking at the code it might be hard to figure out where exactly the bug is.

Comment: Does an AND without a second expression cause a problem?

Comment: AND is a binary expression. So it requires 2 expressions. Not sure how *exactly* django is handling the code right now in your case

Comment: I think I fixed the problem you described, but it still does not work (see my question for update)

Comment: is `represents` a `datetime` ? if so, `__exact` may not work. Just use `=`

Comment: Nope. But even if it didn't work, than I still wouldn't be getting these results. EVERYTHING in the table is being returned... it's quite strange.

Comment: One way to debug - query against the sub `Q` parameters generated, and see if they work individually